# QMessageBox exec doesnt seem to return QDialog::DialogCode

Tags: c++, qt

My application's `closeEvent()` looks nearly like this (Qt 5.8.0 on Windows):

```
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    if(some_changes_were_made)  // bool
    {
        QMessageBox mbox;
        mbox.setText("Page(s) have been changed.");
        mbox.setInformativeText("What do you want to do?");
        mbox.addButton("Exit now", QMessageBox::AcceptRole);
        mbox.addButton("Save page(s) first", QMessageBox::RejectRole);

        int exit_code = mbox.exec();

        if(exit_code == QDialog::Rejected)
        {
           // bail out of the close event so the user can save pages
           event->ignore();
           return;
        }
    }

    event->accept();
}
```

I'm curious if the documentation is wrong, which states that `exec()` returns a `QDialog::DialogCode`.  It actually seems to return the `QMessageBox::ButtonRole` (which interestingly is the inverse value).  Or am I just doing something totally wrong here?

Please forgive any typos, as I'm unable to copy the actual code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [QMessageBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html) reference here.

It is supposed to return one of the [standardButton](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#StandardButton-enum) replies. You are using `QDialogBox` replies, `QMessageBox` has already overriden `QDialogBox`'s `exec` method.

You want to check something like this:

```
switch (exit_code) {
  case QMessageBox::Save:
      // Save was clicked
      break;
  case QMessageBox::Discard:
      // Don't Save was clicked
      break;
  case QMessageBox::Cancel:
      // Cancel was clicked
      break;
  default:
      // should never be reached
      break;
}
```

Source from the same link.